# How to insert a column between two rows of another column during responsiveness in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My normal layout is:

```
|A||C|

|B||C|
```

There are two columns - left and right.
'A' and 'B' are two rows of left column
'C' is right column.

When I resize, i want it to respond like:

```
|A|

|C|

|C|

|B|
```

Code:

```
<div class="container row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                a
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                b
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        c
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I have found the solution based on Dan's

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red">a</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 visible-xs" style="background-color: blue">c</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: orange">b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: blue">c</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: reordering is built into bootstrap using push and pull, see my working fiddle below

Comment: If you look at your question above, you'll see an **edit** button at the bottom. You can modify your question to add your code that way. Keep in mind that the goal of Stack Overflow is to make your post useful to others who may have the same needs as you in the future.

Comment: Please mark Dan's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding of your needs this is how you accomplish your reordering using bootstrap the way it was intended:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">a</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">c</div>
        <div class="col-sm-push-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">c</div>
        <div class="col-sm-pull-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8752/)

Here's a [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to the official bootstrap documentation on ordering.

**Update based on comments:**

Here's a solution using bootstrap exclusively:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">a</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">c</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 visible-xs">c</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 visible-xs">b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">c</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">b</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8765/)

Comment: I think you got confused with the diagram,
I have just two columns:
1: a,b
2: c

They are all in a single row
a and b are two sub-rows of the left column

Comment: you should show some code or provide a fiddle to save everyone (including yourself) a bit of time.

Comment: If you have two divs acting as columns and you want to move one of your child divs into another that's a bit more complicated. I think you may need to employ bootstraps **hidden** or jquery's **append**

Comment: this is the code

<div class="container row">
 <div class="col-sm-8" style="border-color: red">
   <div class="row">
    a
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    b
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4" style="border-color: green">
  c
 </div>
</div>

i need id to collapse to three rows a,c,b when re-sized,

thanks for the solution,
is there a work around?

Comment: there's always a workaround @sidb :) Also, you can update your main post, just click the edit button! give that a shot and I'll take a look at the code you provided

Comment: thanks, i modified yours to get it working,
and as you can tell, i am new to stack

Comment: If my answer showed you what you needed be sure to mark  this as the answer. It'll help others in the future to find the solution quicker and give both you and I rep.

Answer (score 0):

`.col-*-push-*` and `.col-*-pull-*` are used to reorder columns for differnt screen sizes. So you would use `.col-sm-pull-6` on column C2 and `.col-sm-push-6` on column B. Simply adjust the amount of columns you need to push / pull to your layout.

Learn more at : getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score -1):

could also use float as a solution (if you don't feel like using push/pull)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 a">
    AAA            
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 c">
        CCC
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 c">
        CCC
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 b">
        BBB
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.a,.b,.c{height:60px;}
.a{background:red;}
.b{background:yellow;}
.c{background:blue;float:right;}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .c{float:none;}
```

Here's a jsfiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8757/)

Comment: Working against framework conventions is generally frowned upon unless completely necessary. Ignoring Bootstrap's push-pull conventions could lead to unintended layout side effects down the road and extra css bloat.